# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No field a of type Lcom/google/gson/TypeAdapterFactory

Tags: android, gson

**java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No field a of type Lcom/google/gson/TypeAdapterFactory; in class Lay; or its superclasses (declaration of 'ay' appears in /data/app/com.adenda.example-1/base.apk)**

it appear when i enable proguard.
i define proguar rules for gson

```
-keep class com.google.common.** { *; }

-keep class com.google.gson.** { *; }

-dontwarn com.google.common.**

-keep class com.google.gson.Gson



-keep public class * extends com.google.gson.TypeAdapter

-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }

-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }
```

`

Comment: You defined too many rules https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg

Comment: As your suggestion i change my proguard rules but get same error.

Comment: Well `TypeAdapterFactory` is kept in that link, so I don't think you get the same error at all

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. Just keep all enums :

```
-keepclassmembers enum * { *; }
```

Or keep alive the needed one :

```
-keepclassmembers enum com.your.package.** { *; }
```

In mine case those problems were caused because of enums. Not sure if that's your case.

Comment: How would this fix OP's issue? I mean how can Gson type adapters and Java enums be so relevant to share the same ProGuard rules?

Comment: Sorry, I was answering in hurry. I thought that u were facing the problem with enums as classmembers. I had one of them recently. So, my answer is completely wrong. This happened for me when TypeAdapter$EnumTypeAdapter<init> was called. Once more - sorry if this answer confused u.